# jQuery Cycle pagerAnchorBuilder issue with IE8 and lower

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, cycle

The following code:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <div>
       <h2>Surveys</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
         <p class="more"><a href="#" title="XXXXX>XXXXX</a></p>
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>

$('.tabs ul')
  .after('<div class="nav">')
     .cycle({
       cleartypeNoBg:true,
       timeout:10000,
       speed:350,
       pause:1,
       pager:'.tabs .nav',
       pagerAnchorBuilder:function(idx,slide){
       return'<a href="#">'+$(slide).find('.more a').attr('title')+'</a>';
   }
});
```

works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE9, but in IE8 and lower, I get twice as many tabs and half of them say 'undefined'. If I move the anchor so that it wraps around all the contents (i.e. just inside the `<li>`) then IE8 shows the correct tabs, but that doesn't really work with what I'm trying to accomplish.

Is there any way to get this to work in IE8 with the markup I have currently?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the whole pageanchorbuilder thing, it's way to basic for doing anything fancy. It also forces you into using lists, which I think is where you're problems are coming from (IE8 and lists == trouble!). This is what I found worked better.

First build out your Cycle stage and thumb tray like this. You now have complete control over the format!

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="stage">
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-tray">
        <div class="thumb">Anything in here</div>
        <div class="thumb">Anything in here</div>
        <div class="thumb">Anything in here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use this JS to link the thumbnails to the slides. Basically, thumb 1 links to slide 1 and so on.

```
// Start Cycle
jQuery('.stage').cycle({ 
    timeout:  0,
});

// Make the thumbs change the stage
jQuery('.gallery .thumb').click(function(){
    var thumbIndex = jQuery(this).closest('.gallery').find('.thumb').index(jQuery(this));
    jQuery(this).closest('.gallery').find('.stage').cycle(thumbIndex);
});
```

This will work with multiple Cycle gallery's on a page too. I think will solve your problems.